# empty array at objectForKey crashes iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json

I have an array that gets created from JSON. The array looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "img": "images/photo_10.jpg", 
        "title": "None", 
        "photo_comments": [
            {
                "body": "my comment", 
                "author": "john", 
                "created": "2011-04-17 14:21:11"
            }
        ], 
        "id": 24
    }, 
    {
        "img": "images/photo_8.jpg", 
        "title": "None", 
        "photo_comments": [], 
        "id": 22
    }


]
```

I pass the array to a function that enumerates thru the dictionary and creates a string then adds it to a comments array.  My code looks like this:

```
    -(NSArray *)formatCommentArray:(NSArray *)array  
{

    NSMutableArray *comments = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

    for (NSDictionary *photo in array)
    {   


           for( NSDictionary *comment in [photo objectForKey:@"photo_comments"])
           {

               NSString *commentString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %@", 
                                           [comment objectForKey:@"author"], [comment objectForKey:@"body"]];



               [comments addObject:commentString];


           }




    return comments;

}
```

The app appears to crash because not all my photos have comments and when it gets to an empty array it comes to a halt. I've tried some "if statements" and a few other tricks to no avail.  I used this code successfully to create an array of images, but obviously the value for the "img" key was NOT an array with a dictionary.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pasting the crash log/error messages can be useful to identify errors. Considering @rgeorge’s answer is correct (it seems so), you should’ve received an ‘unrecognised selector sent to instance’ exception.

Comment: Also, `[[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease]` is equivalent to `[NSMutableArray array]`.

Comment: Ah, I see, so just use the convenience method, no need to alloc and init?

Comment: No need to `+alloc/-init/-autorelease`. You can use both since they’re equivalent but `+array` is more concise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, `[[comment objectForKey:@"photo_comments"] objectForKey:@"author"]` is trying to use objectForKey on an array, which won't work. Looking at your json, photo_comments is a (potentially empty) list, containing objects. You need one more list loop in there.

```
for (NSDictionary *photo in array)
{
  // do stuff with photo.img, photo.title etc

  for (NSDictionary *comment in [photo objectForKey:@"photo_comments"])
  {
    // do stuff with comment.author, comment.body etc
  }
}
```

(add error checking to suit.)

Comment: OK, this code allowed me to successfully get the comment. However, my array only has one object in it.  I need my comments array to account for the photo that doesn't have a comment.  An empty string should suffice, but I'm not sure how to code that. And if a photo has multiple comments, I guess I would need to create a sub-array and add it to my comments array. Any thoughts?  You have been most helpful thus far.  Thanks

Comment: I've updated the formatCommentArray code that allowed me to successfully create the single object array.